# Manage user permission Google Analytics API v3

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I'm using the Google Analytics API to add users to a Google Analytics account.

I'm using the following POST endpoint to do so.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/${accountID}/entityUserLinks
```

I want to grant users permissions based on the roles available in the Google Analytics dashboard (Admin, Editor, Marketer, Analyst, etc...)

However, according to the documentation I'm only able to add the following permissions.

[image: Google analytics API documentation on user permissions outlining the following permissions: MANAGE_USERS, EDIT, COLLABORATE, READ_AND_ANALYZE]

How do I add the permissions/roles available natively on the Google Analytics dashboard? [image: User permissions listed on Google analytics dashboard: Administrator, Editor, Marketer, Analyst, Viewer, None]

Here is my request body:

```
{
    'permissions': {
        'local': [
            ...
        ]
    },
    'userRef': {
        'email': agencyData.linkedAccounts.Google.email
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't add users to UA analytics accounts they should be shut down

Comment: Is there a user management API in v4?

Comment: Yes the admin API